# RewriteCond according to the first part of url not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to work on doing some rewrite but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(static/|server/|internal.php).*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /internal.php?request=$1 [L]
```

I'm trying to redirect everything to `/internal.php?request=blablabla`, except the internal.php itself, and things in two folders called static and server, since these two folders have images and so on.

For example,

`/hello/world` => `/internal.php?request=hello/world/`

`/static/a/b/c/a.jpg` => `/static/a/b/c/a.jpg` *not changed*

But the code is not working, the RewriteCond seems not able to restrict rewrite of internal.php, and the two folders. Now what's happening is everything is going to rewrite to internal.php, and internal.php would be rewrite to internal.php again. And finally give me a 500 after infinite loops. Which I don't want any rewrite happen. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a leading `/` in the request URI expression, also you should escape the dot in `internal.php` so that it actually matches a dot instead of every char:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(static/|server/|internal\.php).*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /internal.php?request=$1 [L]
```

Note that this will also rewrite `/static` and `/server` where the trailing slash is omitted, if you want to avoid that you could for example add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(static|server)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(static/|server/|internal\.php).*$
```

Tough it should be possible to put this in a single expression, however I'm not that experienced with regular expressions, so I'm pretty sure that this not the most elegant way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(((static|server)(/.*)?)|(internal\.php.*))$
```